# How to override Trix HTMLSanitizer to allow span tags with class

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, trix

I need to allow span tag with class in the trix editor.

I could achive adding span tag by

```js
 Trix.config.textAttributes.span = {
        tagName: "span",
        inheritable: true
 };
```

But I can't get class on span it is still getting stripped by the Trix.HTMLSanitizer I guess.

I also tried with

```js
 Trix.config.textAttributes.span = {
        tagName: "span",
        inheritable: true,
        parser: false
 };

//and


 Trix.config.textAttributes.span = {
        tagName: "span",
        inheritable: true,
        parser: (element) => {
         element.allowedAttributes = 'class';
        }
 };
```

Can't figure out how to override the Trix.HTMLSanitizer to allow something like `<span class="my-class">value</span>` to show up styled in the editor.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same need and ended up using a hack to work around the problem: I restyled the `.trix-content del` element in CSS. This only works if you just need a single custom style, though. (I could do this because I didn't need the strikethrough formatting, so I could (ab)use that tag.)

To make it nicer, I then replaced the `del` tag with a proper `span class="xxx"` in the content whenever I needed to display the text anywhere other than in the Trix editor itself. That is, I used `del` internally to mark up, store and edit/update the content, and swapped it out for a proper `span` to display to the user outside the editor.

On creation of the rich-text content, to mark it for highlighting:

```rb
def create
  ...
  object_params[:content].gsub!(/foo/i, '<del>\0</del>')
  ...
end
```

Then, when loading it for display outside the editor:

```rb
@new_content = @object.content.to_s.gsub(/<del>/i, '<span class="highlight">').gsub(/<\/del>/i, '</span>').html_safe
```

And the SCSS:

```
// Trix-editor

.trix-content {
  del {
    background-color: $yellow;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

.highlight {
  background-color: $yellow;
}
```

This may not do what you need and is a bit nasty in any case. It would be great if Trix could support arbitrary `span` tags!

(FWIW, my need was to scan the text file and highlight certain words for the user.)